# Capturing serial data in background process

Tags: python, serial-port, subprocess, pyserial

I am currently trying to capture serial data within a python script. I intend to begin capturing a log of all the data captured on a serial port while the rest of the script continues to interact with the system I am testing.

If I use pyserial I believe it will end up blocking the rest of the tests I want to carry out until I finish logging.

My options I have considered are:

- Writing another script to capture logs using pyserial, call this script using subprocess.Popen()
- Using built in unix tools such as tail or cat and calling these with subprocess.Popen()

I am sure I could find a way to get either of these to work, but if anyone knows of a more direct way of doing it then I would love to know.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can get your answer from another post [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585238/subprocess-in-reading-serial-port-read/13585959#13585959

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why create another process for reading data from pySerial ?
For non-blocking the read you can configure the timeout in serial class.
e.g.

```
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate = 19200
ser.port = 0
ser.timeout = 2 #By default, this is set to None
ser.open()
```

Also look at the wrapper class for reference.

http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/examples.html#wrapper-class

You can run a thread to keep reading the data from serial and update it to the buffer.

Creating another process invloves the overhead of IPC and not recommended for this task.

Comment: I thought that specifying the timeout would mean it stops gathering data after the timeout? I will look into the wrapper class now.

Comment: Specifying the timeout means it "stops gathering the data after data reception stops". It is the way of telling, if data stops for 5 sec, come out of the function. Not after the timeout it stops reading.

Comment: OK, thank you for the clarification. I am currently reading more about thread control in python. I've never done anything with it before. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

you can always check if there is available data with `ser.inWaiting()` [see link](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.inWaiting)

```
from serial import Serial
ser = Serial(port=0, baudrate=19200) # set the parameters to what you want
while 1:
    if ser.inWaiting():
        temp = ser.read()
    #all the other code in the loop
```

if there is no data available to read the loop skips the serial reading

or if the data is to time sensitive you can do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585238/subprocess-in-reading-serial-port-read/13585959#13585959)