# Subprocess in Reading Serial Port Read

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Hi I am using Serial port communication to one of my device using python codes. It is sending a set of Hex code, Receives a set of data. process it.

This data has to be stored in to a database.

I have another script that has MYSQLdb library pushing it in to the database.

If I do that in sequentially in one script i lose a lot in sampling rate. I can sample up to 32 data sets per second if I dont connect to a database and insert it in to the table.

If I use Multiprocessing and try to run it my sampling rate goes to 0.75, because the parent process is waiting for the child to join. so how can i handle this situation.

Is it possible to run them independently by using a queue to fill data?

Comment: not sure what you mean by "waiting for the child to join"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use threading and Queue.

here is an example:

```
from Queue import Queue
import threading
import serial

def readline(ser,output):
    threadLock.acquire()# Get lock to synchronize threads
    output.put(ser.readline())
    threadLock.release()# Free lock to release next thread
    # this will go on forever until you kill the program

if __name__=='__main__':
    output = Queue()
    with serial.Serial(com,baudrate=115200,timeout=1) as ser:
        ser_thread = threading.Thread(target=readline, args=(ser,output,))
        ser_thread.start()
        while(True):
             threadLock.acquire()#wait until lock is free
             try:
                 data=output.get()
             threadLock.release()# Free lock to release next thread
             # do somthing with data
```

Answer (score 1):

use a pipe.
Ceate two processes using the `subprocess` module, the first reads from the serial port and writes the set of hex codes to stdout. This is piped to the second process which reads from stdin and updates the database.

Comment: i made a queue in each process and passed data between both parent and child. It worked very well. The key part is to introduce a shorter timeout so the sampling rate is maintained.